# React Material table sorting

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I am trying to worrk with react material Table V2.I have a common table then Im passing columns as props.Ild like the sorting to be initialy false but one can define the columns that are sortable.My challenge is if I set enableSort as False then everything is unsortable and  I cant set a sortable column.When I dont set that everything is sortable.and if I set  initial values everythinfg is still sortable.Anyone who has been able to work with this

I tried setting enableSort on table but everything was not sortable and I could not overwrite it by defining in column.Then I tried removing the enable sort and everything was initially sortable.Ild like the table to have  like an  initial state where everything is not sortable then for those columns that are sortable,we send them as props or set using the enableSortProp.below is my code.Kindly help

```
import {
  MaterialReactTable,
  useMaterialReactTable,
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  MRT_RowData,
  // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
  type MRT_ColumnDef,
} from 'material-react-table'
type initialSortProps = {
  id: string
  desc: boolean
}
type CommonTableProps<T extends MRT_RowData> = {
  // Use T instead of any for MRT_ColumnDef
  columns: MRT_ColumnDef<T>[]
  data: T[]
  initialSortValues: initialSortProps[]
}

const getTableRowStyles = (isOdd: boolean) => ({
  ...(isOdd && {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  }),
  '& td, & th': {
    border: 0,
  },
})
const CommonTable = <T extends MRT_RowData>({
  columns,
  data,
  initialSortValues,
}: CommonTableProps<T>) => {
  const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    enableTopToolbar: false,
    enableToolbarInternalActions: false,
    enableColumnActions: false,

    paginationDisplayMode: 'pages',
    enablePagination: true,
    initialState: {
      sorting: initialSortValues,
    },

    muiTablePaperProps: {
      elevation: 0,
    },
    muiTableProps: {
      sx: {
        border: '1px #f0f0f0 solid',
        borderRadius: '6px',
      },
    },
    muiTableHeadCellProps: {
      align: 'left',
      sx: {
        fontFamily: 'Instrument sans',
        fontSize: '12px',
        color: '#7e7e7e',
        fontWeight: 500,
      },
    },
    muiTableBodyCellProps: {
      align: 'left',
      sx: {
        border: 'none',
      },
    },
    muiTableBodyRowProps: ({ row }) => {
      return {
        sx: getTableRowStyles(row.index % 2 === 1),
      }
    },

    muiPaginationProps: {
      rowsPerPageOptions: [10],
      shape: 'rounded',

      showRowsPerPage: false,
      variant: 'outlined',
      sx: {
        '& .Mui-selected': {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          border: '1px solid #5DAA97',
          color: '#5DAA97',
          '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })

  return (
    <div className=' h-full relative'>
      <MaterialReactTable
        table={table}
        columns={columns.map((col) => ({
          ...col,
          sorting: col.sortable !== undefined ? col.sortable : true, // set sortable if defined, default to true
        }))}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default CommonTable`
```